# Lenovo trackpad not working

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I am using a Lenovo laptop and recently my trackpad has stopped working. I have a wireless mouse but sometimes I prefer to use the trackpad.

I tried updating the drivers but it said it has the latest version installed and I checked the settings and it doesn't seem to be disabled.

Comment: What Lenovo laptop?

Comment: @spike_66 lenovo_mt_20405_bu_idea_fm_lenovo flex 2-15

Answer (score 0):

• Try reinstalling the drivers

• Remove the wireless mouse's USB.

• Some kind of a malfunction going on there in your trackpad. Try consulting a technician.

Comment: I just noticed in the bottom right corner in the taskbar the Touch Pad icon has a red X through it does that mean anything

Comment: The red X means that the touchpad is disabled. Press the F6 key and see if it works. Otherwise see in the Device Manager if the touchpad is disabled.

Comment: just like @spike_66 said, it is disabled. If not maybe the drivers are not installed, try troubleshooting it.